# What to include in gitignore in an EPiServer project

Tags: episerver

Tried http://www.gitignore.io/api/episerver but it only gives me the following:

```
# Created by http://www.gitignore.io

### EPiServer ###
######################
## EPiServer Files
######################
*License.config
```

Is there some community maintained .gitignore someplace on the interwebs one could use or what do you have in your projects?

Comment: This is what I usually use. https://gist.github.com/nimeshjm/efa9bf0f351a198eb5eb   It's basically a standard .Net gitignore file with the license file and modulesbin folder exclusion.

Comment: During the most recent project, where i had to deal with config files and transformations, i would exclude *.config as well. (every developer will have a different local environment, have a separate folder with the base/standard configs, so everyone can setup their own env)

Answer (score 0):

I personally have the following ignored:

- App_Data/Index
- App_Data/blobs
- modulesbin
- License.config